# Electron Manipulate/Intercept WebView Requests and Responses

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

I want to create an Electron app that will use [webview](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag) to display 3rd party content.

I would like to be able to intercept all requests and responses from this webview. Sometimes I would like to manipulate this content, other times I would like to log it, and other times I’d like to do nothing.

As one example for the responses, maybe a web server will respond with TypeScript code, maybe I want to take that response, and compile it to standard JavaScript.

I have looked into [this page](https://discuss.atom.io/t/electron-intercept-http-request-response-on-browserwindow/21868/6?u=fishcharlie) but it looks like it is only possible to cancel requests, and manipulate the headers. The [WebRequest API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request) doesn't look to fit the needs of my use case since it only allows very minor manipulations of requests and responses.

I have also considered setting up some time of web server that can act as a proxy, but I have concerns about that. I want to maintain user privacy, and I want to ensure that to the web servers that host the 3rd party content it looks like the request is coming from a browser like environment (ex. Electron webview) instead of a server. I know I can manipulate requests with the headers I send and such, but this whole solution is getting to be a lot more complicated, then I would like, but might be the only option.

Any better ways to achieve this, and have more control over the Electron webview?

Comment: I'm making an Electron browser of sorts that will only render web pages / execute code that has been code signed with a pre-shared key so I can serve web apps from untrustworthy web servers (in this post-Snowden world, no web server is trustworthy). So I need to intercept response bodies, extract their signatures, and validate them. If a signature is missing or invalid, I must kill the WebView before it can render / run the page, or replace the response body with a warning message or something. So I'm very interested in what you've asked.

Comment: This is not possible currently with chrome/extension. As you can modify responses. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058. So you should look at building a proxy server for this

Comment: @TarunLalwani It sounds like for both GuilhermeVieira and myself that privacy is a major issue. So a proxy server doesn’t seem like a secure method that we are looking for. Unless the proxy server was a local server or something, to ensure that privacy and security are maintained. If you have example code for that I’d recommend writing an answer :)

Comment: I thought about creating a local proxy server and use the redirection API to make requests go through it, but that would make the site origin become `https://localhost:somePort` instead of the original origin. Maybe using the regular proxy API could help with that, I'll take a look later. I just found out that Firefox has an API for this that works even for browser extensions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData. It's a shame Chromium / Electron don't have one :(

Comment: This looks promising, but I don't have the time to give it a try right now: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487422#c29. @CharlieFish, if you do, please let me know :)

Comment: did u figure out how to do it, and by it i simply mean capturing responses from the server?? im trying to do this exact same thing with `webview` right now

Comment: A proxy won't do it, as - at least on TLS/SSL websites, which constitute something like 95% of the web in terms of traffic - proxies cannot see the request bodies, not even the full URL, they're just passing back and forth cyphertext that is meaningless to them. You'd have to be able to alter the trusted certificate authorities on the client, which is probably a lot of work and highly suspicious, see https://serverfault.com/questions/59334/could-my-enterprise-proxy-know-the-content-of-an-https-request for more details.

Answer (score 18):

I think you should look into the [Protocol API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol). It works as a proxy internally.

Say you want the user, when opening `http://www.google.com`, to see content like `you've been conned!`:

```js
const { protocol } = require("electron");

const content = new Buffer("you've been conned!");

protocol.interceptBufferProtocol("http", (request, result) => {
  if (request.url === "http://www.google.com")
    return result(content);
  ... // fetch other http protocol content and return to the electron
});
```

There's lots of work to do, compared to the [WebRequest API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request), but it's much simpler than an independent local proxy.

Comment: However down voted this, care to explain why? It looks quite promising. @notXX, can this be used to patch the contents of an HTTPS response?

Comment: at first i just wrote "I think you should look into The Protocol API.", so it is down voted. it is not really like patch the contents, more like a proxy. if you intercept the HTTPS protocol, you must handle ALL HTTPS requests, so there's lots of work.

Comment: maybe we could register a custom protocol, and use webRequest.onBeforeRequest to redirect selected requests to the custom protocol. interecpt entire protocol is messy.

Comment: That's exactly what I want tbh, may not be what Charlie wants though. Question is: When you write the result, does it have to be SSL-encrypted? I guess so. But in that case I could use a self-signed certificate, then tell Electron to ignore certificate errors. Since the proxy code itself would use an HTTPS library that validates certificates, there should be no security issue there, and the document origin (protocol, hostname, and port) would be intact... This looks really promising, thanks :)

Comment: glad to be helpful. i think the protocol API is above the transportation layer like HTTPS or HTTP or FILE. so maybe just dumping the document to electron is enough.

Comment: I'm also curious how to intercept only certain request having a certain path. I made new questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943365 and https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-can-we-use-protocol-interceptfileprotocol-with-only-certain-paths-leaving-other-requests-untouched/64968

Comment: I'm trying this now, and it seems to work beautifully for intercepting response bodies.

Comment: That sounds like a quite viable solution, and not that hard to do at first glance, as you'd just need to forward the requests you don't care about unaltered and only intervene for the ones you're interested in. I'll try this approach in a project of mine where, for an academic experiment, I need to tamper with the responses of a popular app to evaluate how user behaviour is affected, and I'd also like to be able to do it on mobile.

Comment: See also: Electron issue requesting functionality to call the original handler: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15434

Answer (score 6):

To get the request body of any http network call made by your electron app:

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders(filter, (details, callback) => {
        if (details.uploadData) {
            const buffer = Array.from(details.uploadData)[0].bytes;
            console.log('Request body: ', buffer.toString());
        }
        callback(details);
      })
```

Comment: Yes, but you can't alter the response, and I'm not even sure you can view it.