# How can we use electron.protocol.interceptFileProtocol with only certain paths, leaving other requests untouched?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'd like to intercept certain HTTP requests and replace them with files. So I thought I could use `electron.protocol.interceptFileProtocol` like so:

```js
protocol.interceptFileProtocol('http', (request, callback) => {
  // intercept only requests to "http://example.com"
  if (request.url.startsWith("http://example.com")) {
    callback("/path/to/file")
  }

  // otherwise, let the HTTP request behave like normal.
  // But how?
})
```

How do we allow other `http` requests other than `http://example.com` to continue working as normal?

Comment: any idea how i can capture the requests/responses from a `webview`?? ive been stuck on this problem for a while now. here is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816741/capture-webview-requests-and-responses)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is a way to do this exactly? but I did something similar which is to use `session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest

something like

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest({urls: ['http://example.com']}, function(details, callback) {
  callback({
    redirectURL: 'file://' + this.getUrl(details.url)
  });
});
```

If you need more than a redirect you could redirect to your own custom protocol (eg. a url like `mycustomprotocol://...`). You can implement your own protocol handler with `protocol.registerStringProtocol`, etc.

I used both onBeforeRequest and registerStringProtocol separately in electron without issues so far but never both together - should work together though I geuss.

Comment: any idea how i can capture the requests/responses from a `webview`?? ive been stuck on this problem for a while now. here is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816741/capture-webview-requests-and-responses)

Comment: This just seems to hang for some reason.

Comment: is it working? because I have the same problem as here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12242
What electron version did you use? I'm on 5.0.13

Comment: I've been trying this with both a file protocol and by registering a custom protocol, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

When using `protocol.interceptXXXXProtocol(scheme, handler)`, we are intercepting scheme protocol and uses handler as the protocol’s new handler which sends a new XXXX request as a response, as said [in the doc here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol-ns#protocolinterceptfileprotocolscheme-handler).

However, doing so totally breaks the initial handler for this specific protocol, which we would need after handling the callback execution. Thus, we just need to restore it back to its initial state, so that it can continue working as normal :)

Let's use: `protocol.uninterceptProptocol(scheme)`

```
protocol.interceptFileProtocol('http', (request, callback) => {
  // intercept only requests to "http://example.com"
  if (request.url.startsWith("http://example.com")) {
    callback("/path/to/file")
  }

  // otherwise, let the HTTP request behave like normal.
  protocol.uninterceptProtocol('http');
})
```

Comment: Nice! It's been a long-time coming for an answer.

Comment: I haven't tested this. Is this the same as removing an event listener? The description says "Remove the interceptor installed for scheme and restore its original handler.". If I understand correctly, the very first time we receive an `http` request, and regardless if it is for example.com or not, the handler will be removed, and then we'll never handle any future requests. If my understanding is correct, then this won't work. We need to handle `example.com` request every time, and otherwise make it continue as normal every time.

Comment: You are indeed right. I guess what we are missing here is the current implementation of the default/original handler. If we had access to it then we could just overwrite it, by using it in an if/else condition block.

Comment: That would be nice!