# How to modify a response in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

Let's say that I'm using a `GET` request on `https://example.com` and the response is this:

```
This is a response message.
```

How would I modify it in a way so that in my code, so that it can change the response to say something like this:

```
This is a MODIFIED response message.
```

For example, if my Electron app were to navigate to `https://example.com`, the screen would show me the modified content instead of the original content.

Essentially, I am trying to literally modify the request.

I have based my code off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51372954) but it only shows a proof of concept with a pre-typed `Buffer`, as in my situation I'd like modify the response instead of outright replacing it. So, my code looks like this:

```js
protocol.interceptBufferProtocol("http", (req, CALLBACK) => {
  if(req.url.includes("special url here")) {
  var request = net.request({
    method: req.method,
    headers: req.headers,
    url: req.url
  });
  request.on("response", (rp) => {
    var d = [];
    rp.on("data", c => d.push(c));
    rp.on("end", () => {
      var e = Buffer.concat(d);
      console.log(e.toString());
      // do SOMETHING with 'e', the response, then callback it.
      CALLBACK(e);
    });
  });
  request.end();
  } else {
    // Is supposedly going to carry out the request without interception
    protocol.uninterceptProtocol("http");
  }
}
```

This is supposed to manually request the URL, grab the response and return it. Without  the protocol event, it works and gives me a response, but after some debugging, this piece of code consistently calls the same URL over and over with no response.

There is also the [WebRequest API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-request), but there is no way of modifying the response body, you can only modify the request headers & related content.

I haven't looked fully into Chromium-based solutions, but after looking at [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058), I'm not sure if it is possible to modify the response so it appears on my app's end in the first place. Additionally, I'm not familiar with the Chromium/Puppeteer messages that get sent all over the place.

Is there an elegant way to have Electron to get a URL response/request, call the URL using the headers/body/etc., then save & modify the response to appear different in Electron?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your protocol interception handler recursively invokes itself because the `net.request` leads to another invocation of the same protocol. You could avoid this by inserting a special header that ends the recursion:

```js
if (req.url.includes("special url here") &&
    !req.headers["x-request-interception"]) {
  var request = net.request({
    method: req.method,
    headers: {...req.headers, "x-request-interception": "true"},
    url: req.url
  });
  ...
} else {
    // Is supposedly going to carry out the request without interception
    protocol.uninterceptProtocol("http");
  }
}
```

Instead of adding a special header, you could also use a special value for the `User-Agent` header.

Am I right to assume that once the `else` branch has been executed, request interception is switched off completely? This would mean that each run of your electron program can intercept only *one* request in total. A less drastic `else` branch is given in Vinutha's answer.