# Intercept HTTP response body of requests in Electron webview

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm working on an Electron app which heavily uses webview to provide a custom interface to a remote site (Salesforce). The webview is loading pages which contain ajax requests. I need to capture the responses to these requests so that I can refactor out the screen scraping the app is currently doing.

I have tried several methods:

[WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974767/electron-manipulate-intercept-webview-requests-and-responses) (Only captures request headers, not response bodies)

[Monkey Patching XMLHttpRequest](https://medium.com/@ddamico.125/intercepting-network-response-body-with-a-chrome-extension-b5b9f2ef9466) (Failed to work after injecting via `preload=` and was extremely difficult to debug in a webview)

`protocol.interceptHttpProtocol` (Did not contain response body from webview)

`mainWindow.webContents.debugger.attach` (Did not work)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "did not work" for the `debugger.attach` method in your question?